# Infrequent Request has been terminated between React Native (Superagent) and Laravel API on iOS

Tags: laravel, react-native, superagent

I've developed an app which is fetching data from the API. I am using round about 15 different sagas to fetch different types of data from the API (GET). The API is based on Laravel 5.5

I am using React Native 0.56 with Superagent 3.8.2 to fetch the information.

Infrequently it happens, that I get the following error when I try to fetch the information. A second later, I can fetch the same data without problems.

This occurs on any request. Not especially in this case but I think this is a good example: I have a Google Map. Any time to user moves the map, I fetch die Pins for the region from the API. If I move the Map for maybe 30 times, this errors occurs once or twice...

```
Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
```

Comment: I've seen this happen with too many open and concurrent XHR requests. Are you using HTTP2 to serve your data? That may help. If not, try cancelling open XHR requests when creating new ones that fetch similar data. Also, try not actually fetching until the panning has stopped, as opposed to during panning.

Comment: Thank you for help! Will try this. Do you know a alternative to superagent or axios to do HTTP2-requests?

Comment: .retry() on superagent's request "solved" the problem for the moment. But will try to follow your other steps too.